# Research for SSD hard drive for a cheap slow laptop

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd, sata, hardware-rec

Laptop specification:
[HP 15-db1000AU](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c06263818) notebook with 64 bit AMD Ryzen 3 2.6 GHz with Radeon Vega Graphics, 4GB RAM,  500 GB 5600 rpm HDD with Windows 10 Pro

The computer is very slow (long bootup time, slow to load pictures and video, slow to open a new explorer window, etc) and I have read that using an SSD should significantly increase the speed of this computer. I have never installed an SSD on a laptop before and there seem to be many different kinds of SSD, hence this question.

The laptop's motherboard contains slots for the SATA drive (currently HDD attached) and I think an NVMe type drive (currently empty).
https://droidcops.com/different-types-of-ssd-storage/
I want to replace the SATA HDD with a SATA SSD. I am considering getting something like this:
http://global.11st.co.kr/glb/products/2596084340

Not necessarily this same brand, I might end up buying a WD or Samsung if I can find an affordable one. My current understanding is I can simply pull out my current HDD and insert the SATA SSD, and it should just work, only faster. My questions are:

1. Did I understand this correctly? Since this is a low specification computer I'd rather not spend too much for upgrading it. The cheapest NVMe type drive seems to be more than 3 times more expensive than a SATA one. I am not going to upgrade the RAM. The computer is slow but good enough for the daily things I do on it (Chrome and MS Word, occasional old games). It's not used for anything like video editing or running Android Studio. Given it's specifications can I expect a SATA drive to make it faster?
2. There seem to be different types of SATA as well (https://droidcops.com/different-types-of-ssd-storage/). How can I make sure I get the correct one, that fits the current slot I connect my HDD to? Is a 2.5 inch SATA SDD what I need to look for?
3. Is a SATA SSD for desktop very different from one for a laptop? What should I look for to make sure I get something that fits inside my laptop?
4. Some of these disks I found online have weird sizes (not a power of 2) like 120 GB, 240 GB and 260 GB. Is this normal for SSD drives?
5. I have found some SSD's online that claim to be the same type (2.5 inch, SATA, close to 256 GB, etc) from different companies, but prices seem to vary a lot (one company's SSD sells for around $40 while a similar SSD from Samsung can slightly go above $100). Is this just normal discrepancy between different brands, or should I look more closely at their specifications? I am mostly concerned about the SATA interface not being compatible with the one on my laptop motherboard. I am okay with buying a cheaper brand SSD.
6. Once I get a SATA SSD, in case I am not able to get it to work with my laptop's motherboard for whatever reason, is it still possible to use such drives externally using something like [this](http://global.11st.co.kr/glb/products/3735092444)?

A video showing this laptop disassembly: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dUK0GaI8N9M

Comment: You need to trim this down to remove any hint of it being a 'shopping recommendation' as people will vote to close that rapidly. You also need to trim to one distinct question, not 6.

Answer (score 0):

> Did I understand this correctly? Since this is a low specification computer I'd rather not spend too much for upgrading it. The cheapest NVMe type drive seems to be more than 3 times more expensive than a SATA one. I am not going to upgrade the RAM. The computer is slow but good enough for the daily things I do on it (Chrome and MS Word, occasional old games). It's not used for anything like video editing or running Android Studio. Given it's specifications can I expect a SATA drive to make it faster?

You are using the wrong terminology. Today, HDD and SSD use the same SATA interface. The use of SSD reduces the access time when reading or writing files.
Even a cheap or so-called "slow" SSD will outrun a HDD when used for an operating system because running an operating system is a about handling, mostly reading lots of small files. This use is where access times matter.

> There seem to be different types of SATA as well (https://droidcops.com/different-types-of-ssd-storage/). How can I make sure I get the correct one, that fits the current slot I connect my HDD to? Is a 2.5 inch SATA SDD what I need to look for?

Yes.

> Is a SATA SSD for desktop very different from one for a laptop? What should I look for to make sure I get something that fits inside my laptop?

Your link states "1 TB 5400 rpm SATA". Expect 2,5'' because 3,5'' does not fit in. While the base area of a 2,5'' does not vary, they vary in height. A SSD in 9,5mm might not fit into a machine that is supposed work with 7mm height.

> ```
> Some of these disks I found online have weird sizes (not a power of 2) like 120 GB, 240 GB and 260 GB. Is this normal for SSD drives?
> ```

Yes.

> I have found some SSD's online that claim to be the same type (2.5 inch, SATA, close to 256 GB, etc) from different companies, but prices seem to vary a lot (one company's SSD sells for around $40 while a similar SSD from Samsung can slightly go above $100). Is this just normal discrepancy between different brands, or should I look more closely at their specifications? I am mostly concerned about the SATA interface not being compatible with the one on my laptop motherboard. I am okay with buying a cheaper brand SSD.

Different flash quality translates in different prices. Furthermore the guaranteed lifetime varies. At the end of the lifecycle some SSDs will refuse to work completely. Others still would allow read access to the drive.

> Once I get a SATA SSD, in case I am not able to get it to work with my laptop's motherboard for whatever reason, is it still possible to use such drives externally using something like this?

Yes, but when connecting your drive to an USB 2.0 port you are better off with an interface providing its own power supply like a docking station p.e.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case, the reason for slow operation might be constantly full RAM (mentioned 4GB RAM), and swap cache, in addition to HDD. However, I can pretty much bet that RAM limitations are playing the major part in your system slowness. Windows 10 Pro uses 2 - 3 GB RAM just to boot. Depending on what else you have installed, (Google Chrome can be RAM heavy too, if you have multiple tabs) running programs should trigger heavy swapping.

You can check Task Manager to determine what part of your system is regularly full to the brim, while you are using Google Chrome and other usual tasks, which I am sure will show RAM over HDD. The important metric is seeing if there is any `Free` memory in the `Memory Composition` graph. If it says `Standby`, then there is no Free memory left. If `In use` exceeds 3GB, that alone should trigger constant swapping to HDD.

I strongly suggest you upgrade RAM first if you can. A refurbished 4GB RAM stick would cost you bit less than a new SSD. Assuming your laptop has 2 RAM slots, with only 1 occupied. Carefully note down specifications of your existing RAM stick, which must match: Generation (DDR2/ DDR3/ DDR3L/ DDR4), frequency, CAS Latency, etc.

RAM can be bought refurbished, since there is not enough wear-tear. NEVER think of buying refurbished SSD, since it loses write-cycles quicker than HDD.

---

If you are in the market for SSD, get accustomed to below marketing terms or specifications:

- you can pick up pretty much any good, reputed, trustable brand. This will also help in warranty. Reputable brands will offer you 3 - 5 year standard warranty which is nice to have.
- you are better off picking a SATA SSD, since NVMe support on older laptop is doubtful. SATA SSD is easily compatible with your existing SATA cable that connects your HDD. SATA link speeds are either 3Gb/s or 6Gb/s, higher is better.
- laptop SATA storages are typically 2.5" sizes only.
- they come in standard (256, 512) or  so-called non-standard (250, 500, 1TB) sizes, which is normal.
- higher the write-cycles / endurance, the better. Look for: P/E cycles, or TBW.
- this trivia is only for understanding, but will help you buy right. The lower the bits / cell, the better is the write-cycle / endurance. So SLC(1-bit) **>** MLC(2-bit) **>** TLC(3-bit) **>** QLC(4-bit). But they can be very costly, which is why majority of consumer SSDs are either TLC or QLC, so they come in cheaper.
- check for T.R.I.M. support.